# Is it possible for a date picker to present year/month/day + day name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4

Is it possible to add the day name to the date picker?
For example to dials will show:

(sunday)3   |   11   |   2012

is it even possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you resolve that? I have the same issue....

Answer (score 4):

I think you can not DayName(eg. Sunday)  with Year-Month-Day until you not make it totally custom but you can get the day with date by following code may be  It will help you.

Bind following two IBOutlet in Xib.

and bind method **-(IBAction)GetDateWithDay** with **DatePicker** with **ValueChange** attribut

in .h file

```
IBOutlet UIDatePicker* datePicker;
IBOutlet UILabel* lblDate;
```

in .m file

```
-(IBAction)GetDateWithDay
{

     NSDate* dt = datePicker.date;
     NSDateFormatter* df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
     [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

     NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
     NSInteger units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
     NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:dt];
     NSInteger year = [components year];
     NSInteger day = [components day];

     NSDateFormatter *weekDay = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
     [weekDay setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];

     NSDateFormatter *calMonth = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
     [calMonth setDateFormat:@"MM"];

     lblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %i-%@-%i",[weekDay stringFromDate:dt], day, [calMonth stringFromDate:dt], year];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) It will be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a date picker that will present - also  - the weekday name. Code just to get the weekday won't really help me here..

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code :

http://code4app.net/ios/FlatDatePicker/51cce1d76803fa4b0c000003

http://code4app.net/ios/Custom-DatePicker/51f667d36803fab73f000001

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score -3):

You can use the option DD.
For Example.

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('DD', new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 26));
```

Hope this will help you. [UI/Datepicker/formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)

Comment: The question states objective c and Iphone not jquery